# Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I made a specific runner on my own server, when I try to docker login to gitlab registry, I face with the error message that says "Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searches, I find out that I must specify the DNS configuration in /etc/resolv.conf path, in my case, nameserver 8.8.8.8 was not working because of my location and I had to change it, then login was successful.

Comment: I've added nameserver 8.8.8.8  and it worked. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

reboot the server, it should be back up after.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I changed the IP of my gitlab instance. While I changed the DNS entry for the gitlab application, I forgot to change the DNS entry for the gitlab registry.